# Objective-C Block assigned from Swift is nil after assignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks, swift2

This is highly related to other questions about accessing ObjC callbacks from Swift. But my research is yet to not yield working results.

Anyone able to see if I am possibly doing something wrong syntax wise here?

I've declare the following Objective-C callback as:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class KxMovieDecoder;

typedef void (^KX_FIRST_FRAME_CALLBACK)() ;


extern NSString * const KxMovieParameterMinBufferedDuration;    // Float
extern NSString * const KxMovieParameterMaxBufferedDuration;    // Float
extern NSString * const KxMovieParameterDisableDeinterlacing;   // BOOL

@interface KxMovieViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    KX_FIRST_FRAME_CALLBACK firstFrameLoaded;
}

+ (id) movieViewControllerWithContentPath: (NSString *) path
                               parameters: (NSDictionary *) parameters;

@property (readonly) BOOL playing;
@property (nonatomic, copy) KX_FIRST_FRAME_CALLBACK firstFrameLoaded;

- (void) play;
- (void) pause;

@end
```

When I assign to it from swift code, it is still nil after assignment:

[image: Image showing debug]

```
public func startViewing() -> UIViewController {

        kxMoviePlayer = KxMovieViewController.movieViewControllerWithContentPath(rtspURL, parameters: nil) as? KxMovieViewController
        kxMoviePlayer!.firstFrameLoaded = {
            self.onFirstFrameOfVideo()
        }
```

Comment: What does the implementation of the Objective-C look like?  Just `@synthesize` statements?  Also, your code currently looks like it may create a retain cycle.  If self retains kxMoviePlayer you might consider adding a capture list to your block: `kxMoviePlayer!.firstFrameLoaded = { [unowned self] () -> Void in self.onFirstFrameOfVideo() }`.  This wouldn't cause it to be `nil` though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put together a blank project with a similar set up and it worked fine. A couple of questions though.

Did you mean to have both an instance variable and a property named `firstFrameLoaded`? Your auto-synthesized property is not using the instance variable and is instead using an auto-generated `_firstFrameLoaded` instance variable. Perhaps this is the source of the confusion and you meant to prefix the i-var with an underscore?

Any reason the callback property is a `copy` instead of indicating `strong` or `weak` referencing?

Comment: No reason for the copy, just copied that from another answer on a related question to try to get it to work. What would your recommendation be for the referencing? I originally had strong, nonatomic. And yes let me check the underscore!

Comment: Thank you, yes the mistake I made was the missing _ on the instance variable

Comment: Well it was more out of curiosity as I'm not sure what the bigger picture is. Normally a callback or delegate would have a weak reference because it's not the caller's responsibility to manage the callee's life. I'll see a copy in non-callback cases where you are adding additional processing to a task, but the semantics don't seem right here. Honestly don't know how the copy interacts with the self-referencing closure here though. Seems like a retain cycle. Could be wrong on the copy though.

Comment: Thanks I'll go weak, and manage the retention in the class that creates the callback